# How to use PHP to load a XML file by URL

Tags: php, xml

I want to use PHP to load a XML from a URL like "HTTP://127.0.0.1/19/1", how can I do it? I tried several ways but they all failed.. so just ask for help here..thanks

Comment: What did you try, and why does it fail(error-message)?

Comment: I tried things on this website,
http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Comment: What do you get if you load the URL in a browser?  If you don't see the XML (or, as @qxxx suspects, you see a login prompt) then the problem is with the URL you're using, not PHP/simplexml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$x=simplexml_load_file("HTTP://127.0.0.1/19/1");
?>
```

Comment: I get error like this:failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 401 OK

Comment: 401 means that you need to enter a user/password first... or the request is blocked for some other reason - try this:  $x=simplexml_load_file("HTTP://user:password@127.0.0.1/19/1");  (but I didn't try this)